# velocity/hair to straight an object

Tags: particles, hair

I want to know why my objects don't go straight in velocity hair.
The object already straight in other layer, and the other particle is being straight. but I do wonder why this one doesn't go straight[image]

here is the same setting
[image]

They are being straigh, but I totally don't have idea why the other one is falling.
[image]